# Elementor, font appears too bold

Tags: html, css, fonts, elementor

I am using elementor and the font on my website keeps appearing too bold. From all the possible answers I could find something answers related to font smoothing: antialiased which decreased the weight of the font by a bit but the font still keeps appearing much bolder than it should.

Let me show you an example.

If I open the website inside the elementor builder/editor, the font looks OK.
[image]

But if I open the website itself it appears bolder...
[image]

Can someone help me? I really want to achieve the font-weight that I see in my builder. Since I am trying to follow a concrete design the bold version is quite an issue.

Comment: Most certainly your **front end css** has some overriding rule increasing the heading's font-weight to something like 700. Just inspect your  element in dev tools and try to explicitely set the font-weight to e.g 400.

Answer (score 0):

If you say that font-smoothing is the issue just go add some custom css:

```
body
{
   font-smooth: never!important;
}
```

if you want this to only happen on that page i'm sure that section/div has something wrapping it look for the id/class and you can instead say as an example

```
.thecontainer h2,h3,h4,h5
{
   font-smooth:never!important;
}
```

If that doesnt work for you just force the font weight, if you know what it is great, if not you can inspect on the elemtor editor and go down to the dom element and just have a look what the font weight is.
Then just change it with some custom css again.

```
.headernameorid
 {
   font-weight:400!important;/* Or what ever font-weight you want */
 }
```